# What is the best way to analyse data comparing one by one and stipulate the accuracy?

Tags: classification, variance, computational-statistics

Follow the example:

The first line is the data I got.
The second line is the target data.

```
| 154.0 | 784.4 | 854.1 | 789.3 |
| 153.5 | 789.7 | 892.3 | 903.2 |
```

I want to analyse the accuracy of the obtained data in relation to the target one by one (column by column).

I think that the standard deviation is not a good idea because calculates in relation to avarege, and not one by one.

**EDITED:**

The columns are in chronological order. It is the data that I got from a graph which the x axis is the time, and the y axis is the unit of measurement of my data. So, in the above table, the first column can be 1 hour, and so forth at one-hour intervals.

In the graph below, red is the obtained data and green the target data. I want to know a good way to analyse the accuracy of the red graph in relation to the green graph.

[image: Red-Obtained Data. Green-Target.]

Thanks.

Comment: Are the different columns different variables (eg, height, weight, age, etc)? Do you have multiple observations for each column?

Comment: @gung I edited and added a simple graph.